# Консоль CLion и кодировка сообщений компилятора

Tags: c++, visual-studio, кодировка, clion

Я пытаюсь использовать CLion 2018.2 на Windows 10 с тулчейном от Студии 2017. Студийный cl.exe выводит свои сообщения на русском в кодировке, которую не понимает консоль CLion. Получается подобное:

```
cl: Є®¬ ­¤­ п бва®Є  warning D9025: ЇҐаҐ®ЇаҐ¤Ґ«Ґ­ЁҐ "/std:c++latest" ­  "/std:c++17"
```

Интересует любой вариант решения проблемы: изменить язык компилятора на английский (без переустановки студии или винды), или же изменить кодировку консоли CLion. В интернете пока не нашлось вменяемых способов сделать ни то ни другое.

Обращаю внимание, что это НЕ очередной вопрос про кодировку моих исходников и setlocale.

UPD.
В этой же консоли выводится

```
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: "D:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe" : возвращенный код "0x2"
```

То есть nmake и cl разговаривают разными кодировками?

UPD2.
Нашёл [правильный тикет](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-11641). На момент этой правки ещё не закрыт.

Comment: Ну не используйте CLion… Чем вам студия не угодила? Тем более если компилятор все равно используйте студийный. Что касается кодировки сообщений, то возможно проблема в установке русской локализации для студии.

Comment: нет никаких "русских кодировок". есть cp1251, utf-8 и много других. У Вас студия выводит в CP1251, а глупая idea показывает как CP866 (или наоборот).

Comment: @KoVadim это и так понятно. Делать то что? И да, дело в установке русской локализации на студию. Однако, при установке студия жёстко привязалась к языку системы и не хотела ставить другую версию.

Comment: В идеале подошёл бы ключ для cl.exe, который задаёт язык (или кодировку) сообщений. Но такого нет.

Comment: Правильный ответ - снесите clion. Чуть интереснее ответ - запустите инсталятор студии и снесите оттудова русификатор. Ответ для сильных духом - найдите в настройках clion, где задается кодировка. Или обратитесь в саппорт

Comment: В саппорт уже обращено до нас https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206658129-How-to-set-encoding-in-Message-Output- И ещё: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-2332

Comment: вот это и есть правильно. Тикет в саппорт и ждать.

Answer (score 2):

Решил для себя эту проблему изменением языка программ, не поддерживающих Юникод, в настройках Windows. Для этого нужно:

- В панели управления перейти в: **Панель управления\Часы, язык и регион**.
- Выбрать **Региональные стандарты**.
- Перейти во вкладку **Дополнительно**.
- В настройке **Язык программ, не поддерживающих Юникод** нажать на **Изменить язык системы...**
- Выбрать в качестве текущего языка системы **Английский (США)**.
- Чтобы применить настройки требуется перезагрузить систему.

Язык интерфейса Windows при этом не изменится. Однако, в CLion будут корректно отображаться сообщения компилятора на английском:

```
C:\Users\nano\CLionProjects\cpp_run\main.cpp(24): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
```

Answer (score 2):

К сожалению, [ответ @nano](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/891362/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C-clion-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0/1128950#1128950) в моём случае не помог, к тому же после изменения языка для неюникодных программ сбилась кодировка при ручной компиляции с помощью CMake (компилятором Студии) в консоли.

Оказалось, что достаточно просто поставить кодировку IBM866 (ничего не меняя в системных настройках, язык для неюникодных программ должен остаться русским) в **File** → **Settings...** → **Editor** → **General** → **Console**, пункт «Default Encoding». Правда, ошибки и ворнинги при этом будут не на английском, что иногда помогает, а иногда сбивает с толку.

Answer (score -1):

Вам надо изменить кодировку cmd.exe с cp1251 на UTF-8

p.s.
В `CLion` VS тулчэйн недавно появился, находится в тестировании, так что лучше пока `mingw` или `cygwin` использовать во избежание дальнейших проблем

Comment: скорее всего, Ваш совет не поможет

Comment: @KoVadim у меня всё работает, это проблемы i18n винды, а не нормальных ide и компиляторов, где по умолчанию UTF-8 везде

Comment: это хорошо, что у Вас работает.

Comment: @KoVadim за что минус? оп не написал ещё, помогло ему или нет

Comment: я не ставил. Но скорее всего ему не поможет.

Comment: В вопросе же вроде как идет речь о консоли clion, а не о cmd.exe

Comment: А как её изменить во всей системе, чтобы на консоль clion тоже действовало? [Так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17405182/1690777) + chcp? Но это же костыль, сломает кучу других програм. Или есть способ изменить её внутри clion?